# Recommendation for some papers on simulation of metallic metal

Tags: reference-request, high-performance-computing, physical-properties-of-materials

I want to simulate the collision between two gas giants, the inner layer of gas giant contains the layer of metallic hydrogen and a solid core, if two gas giants collide then the abrubt variation of pressure and temperature may cause the phase change of metallic hydrogen, so in order to simulate the collision between two gas giants precisely we must consider the phase change of metallic hydrogen, so could you please recommend some textbook or paper on the large scale simulation about phase change of metallic hydrogen during the change of pressure and temperature?

Comment: Since metallic hydrogen is a very well-studied system, I guess the "matter modeling" part of your work does not require you to do any new calculations; rather, consulting existing phase diagrams (either computational or experimental) should suffice. With the density, compressibility, etc. data of metallic hydrogen at different temperatures and pressures, you can perform a macroscopic finite-element simulation, which is however beyond the scope of this site.